# TypeScript: is it possible to see errors not in one line?

Tags: quickfix, error, location-list, filetype-typescript

Now I have this:

[image: typescript error]

Sometimes errors are big, and in order to see them clearly - I run `tsc` to see this:

[image: tsc error]

Also, is it possible to see a type name, but not a fields enumeration?

I use [ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) and [tsuquyomi](https://github.com/Quramy/tsuquyomi).

Comment: Assuming the first screenshot is in the location or quickfix list, try `:set wrap` (also [please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/))

Comment: Yes, thanks, `set wrap` works, and is it possible to show type name in error instead of fields?

Comment: For that you probably need to configure the program that produces the output, _or_ work with things like `:help quickfix-functions` to "filter" the program output (assuming it has all the things you need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wrap the lines of any window, you can run `:set wrap`.

To modify error messages, you either need to configure or improve the program that produces them *or* [if all the information is already present and you only need to change the presentation] work with the Quickfix API (`:help quickfix-functions`) to modify the list.